# Parsing List of Strings in Python

Tags: python

I have the following list stored in a variable:

```
names = ['a.lastname1', 'b.lastname2']
```

I would like to parse out the '.' in each string and return a string so it reads  each last name on two lines without the 'a.' and 'b.'

Comment: So what have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: Loop the list, split element on '.', lastly get the last element from the split. That's one solution, go ahead and implement it.

Comment: names[i][2:], I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using [***str.split()***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) function:

```
names = ['a.lastname1', 'b.lastname2']
l1, l2 = (lname.split('.')[1] for lname in names)

print(l1, l2)
```

The output:

```
lastname1 lastname2
```